# Show that a Herman ring cannot occur for a polynomial

Tags: proof-verification, complex-dynamics

I would like to verify my proof of the following statement:

Let $f(z)=z^n + O(z^{n-1})$ be a polynomial. Show that the Fatou set of $f$ does not contain a [Herman ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herman_ring).

Proof:

Suppose otherwise and let $U$ be a Herman ring. By the maximum modulus principle, $f$ attains a maximum on the boundary of $U$. Let $z_0\in \partial U$ be the maximum value. Since $f$ is entire, by maximum modulus principle again, $f$ is constant. This gives a contradiction.

Clearly there is something wrong with this proof; Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conclusion that $f$ is constant is incorrect (if you pick any non-constant polynomial $f$, and any bounded open set $U$, $|f|$ will indeed attain its maximum on $\partial U$).

Hint: you should apply the maximum principle not just to $f$, but to all of $f^n$, and not on the Herman ring, but on the bounded Jordan domain defined by a simple closed curved in the Herman ring.

Comment: Dear Glougloubarbaki 

Thank you for your response. However, I'm afraid I am still unsure. By the bounded Jordan domain, do you refer to the domain $V = \phi^{-1}(\{|z|<r\})$, where $\phi: U\rightarrow \mathbb A_{r,R}$ is the conjugating map? 

Furthermore, I am not sure how applying maximum principle to $V$ and the functions $\{f^{\circ n}\}$ will lead to a contradiction.

Comment: @Timothy: yes, that is the domain. the maximum principle tells you that $\{f^n\}$ is bounded on that Jordan domain, so that it is an open subset of the filled in Julia set, therefore in the Fatou set. this contradicts the fact the $U$ is an annulus. more generally, the same argument tells you that for a polynomial, bounded Fatou components must be simply connected (this is not true for rational maps).