# Herman rings for polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, dynamical-systems, maximum-principle, complex-dynamics

I am reading [this link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9201272.pdf) on complex dynamics and in Problem 12-1 it asks the reader to prove, using the Maximum Modulus Principle, that Herman rings cannot occur for polynomials.

I have seen this question apparently answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3379157/show-that-a-herman-ring-cannot-occur-for-a-polynomial), but I do not really understand it.

As far as I know, for a function $f$, a Fatou component $U$ is a Herman ring if $U$ is conformally isomorphic with an annulus $A_{r,R}$ and $f^p$ is conformally conjugate to a rotation (with irrational angle) of $A_{r,R}$. Hence $U$ contains infinitely many invariant curves $\gamma$ in its interior.

How can I prove the claim using the Maximum Modulus Principle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be a polynomial. If $\deg(f) \leq 1$, then by extending $f$ to an endomorphism of the Riemann sphere, you can show that the Fatou set of $f$ is either the whole sphere or it is biholomorphic to the plane. So in either case, $f$ cannot exhibit a Herman ring.

For the case that $\deg(f) \geq 2$, let $U$ be a bounded Fatou component and let $\Gamma$ be a simple loop in $U$. Let $V$ be the bounded connected component of $\mathbb{C} \setminus \Gamma$ and note that $\partial V = \Gamma$. By the maximum modulus principle, for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$\max_{z \in \overline{V}} |f^n(z)| = \max_{z \in \Gamma} |f^n(z)| \leq M,$$
for some $M > 0$. The inequality follows because $\Gamma$ is a compact subset of $U$ and the sequence of iterates $(f^n)$ is normal on $U$, therefore $(f^n)$ is uniformly bounded on $\Gamma$. This shows that the orbit of any $z \in V$ under $f$ is bounded, and so $V$ is an open set contained in the filled Julia set $K(f)$. Thus, $V \subset \mathbb{C} \setminus J(f)$, where $J(f)$ is the Julia set of $f$, since $V$ cannot intersect $\partial K(f) = J(f)$. Hence, $V \subset U$, as $U$ is a connected component of $\mathbb{C} \setminus J(f)$ and $U \cap V \neq \varnothing$. Since $\Gamma$ was an arbitrary simple loop in $U$, this implies that $U$ cannot be a Herman ring.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I don't get the last part: "since $\Gamma$ was an arbitrary simple loop in $U$, this implies that $U$ cannot be a Herman ring".

Comment: @UriToti well let's say that $U$ was an honest-to-good annulus, then you can take a circle in $U$ whose complement in $\mathbb{C}$ has bounded connected component $V$ containing the bounded connected component of $\mathbb{C} \setminus U$. Then my argument shows that $V \subset U$, which is impossible since $V \cap (\mathbb{C} \setminus U) \neq \varnothing$. You can generalised this argument to an arbitrary domain that is biholomorphic to an annulus by considering a polygonal path, say.